# How to interpret amino acid representation

Tags: proteins, variation, nomenclature

What is the difference between C383S and C383A? For C383S, does it mean Cysteine(C) position 383 in the sequence and its next amino acid connect to it is Serine(S)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that at position 383 the Cysteine(C) is mutated to a Serine(S).  Depending on the organism and gene usually the mutation notation is linked to a specific transcript since the position could vary depending on transcript splicing.

Comment: How about Pro136? Does it means Proline is deleted at position 136?